# show table data in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am developing project management app using Laravel. in my application I have project and one project have many tasks and one task have many comments. so, I have comment table like this,

```
id    comment  project_id
1       abc         1
2       dcf         1
3       fgt         2
4       fgt         2
5       fhgt        1
```

this is my comment controller for comment post

```
public function postNewComment(Request $request, $id, Comment $comment)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'comments' => 'required|min:5',
    ]);

    $comment->comments   = $request->input('comments');
    $comment->project_id = $id;
    $comment->user_id    = Auth::user()->id;
    $comment->save();

    return redirect()->back()->with('info', 'Comment posted successfully');
}
```

and this is my comment model

```
protected $fillable = ['comments', 'project_id'];
```

now I need show comments of the each project when I go to the each project. how can do this?

Answer (score 1):

In your Project model add method

```
public comments()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
}
```

Now in blade you can use

```
@foreach($project->comments as $comment)

{{-- print your commets here --}}

@endforeach;
```

Here is documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: got following error **Undefined variable: project (View: C:\Users\lilan\Desktop\burg\resources\views\comments\form.blade.php)** form.blade.php is my blade in comments folder

Comment: @Lilan you'll need to send the project model in the view whose comments you want to see.

Comment: can you give me hints

Comment: Did you stored object of model to view in your controller?

Comment: In controller: return view('form')->with('project', $project); // $project here is an object of Project model.

Comment: can you anybody give me some cording example